# Как правильно очистить ключи и раздел в реестре

Tags: c#, реестр

Как правильно организовать удаление раздела реестра, и ключей?

```
private static string PathController => @"Software\Cheat Engine";
private static string WinPath => @"Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows";
private static string WinPath2 => @"Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows";
private static string[] CleanDLL = new string[] { "wow64.dll", "user32.dll" };
private static string[] AppReg = new string[] { "AppInit_DLLs", "LoadAppInit_DLLs" };
public static void Sweeping()
{
            bool nTru = true;
            foreach (string subKeyName in CleanDLL) File.Delete(@"C:\" + subKeyName);
            using (var key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(WinPath, nTru))
            {
                using (var key2 = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(WinPath2, nTru))
                {
                    using (var key3 = Registry.CurrentUser)
                    {
                        if (key != null || key2 != null)
                        {
                            foreach (string Finale in AppReg)
                            {
                                key.DeleteValue(Finale);
                                key2.DeleteValue(Finale);
                            }
                        }
                        key3.DeleteSubKeyTree(PathController);
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

На данный момент удаляются только нужные файлы на диске `C:\`

`@"Software\Cheat Engine";` - Раздел который нужно удалить.

---

Разобрался)

```
bool nTru = true;
foreach (string subKeyName in CleanDLL) File.Delete(@"C:\" + subKeyName);
using (var hklm = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine,    
RegistryView.Registry64))
{
   using (var key2 = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(WinPath, nTru))
   {
      using (var key3 = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(WinPath2, nTru))
      {
            foreach (string Dlls in AppReg)
            {
               key2.DeleteValue(Dlls);
               key3.DeleteValue(Dlls);
            }
       }
    }
}
```

Проблема осталась одна, если какого либо ключа или раздела не найдено, то всё падает.

Можно ли сделать проверку если ключи есть в разделе удалить их, если нету, продолжить проходить далее...

Comment: Если раздел в HKML, то вам нужны администраторские права на удаление.

Comment: @VladD, У меня есть права)

Comment: Хорошо, а что происходит? Какое-то исключение бросается?

Comment: Ну и да, что-то ваш код сомнителен. Вы проверяете, не равен ли `null`  _хотя бы один_ из ключей, а потом пытаетесь работать с _обоими_. Если один из них будет `null`, ваш код упадёт. А почему вы не попробуете пройти код под отладчиком?

Comment: Да Вы правы) сейчас проверяю всё от а до я)